# CasperJS querySelectorAll id start with specific string

Tags: css-selectors, casperjs, selectors-api

How do I get all the DIVs starting with ID `div-gpt-ad`?

This is the line

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#div-gpt-ad-1363287890054-0-oop');
```

there are multiple divs with IDs starting with `div-gpt-ad` on my page and I want to get them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=div-gpt-ad]');
```

This will get all `div` tags with an id starting with `div-gpt-ad`.